# Can I post code from a reflector?

Tags: discussion, source-code

In [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377864/was-is-the-performance-of-the-last-extension-method-for-listt/1377895#1377895) I originally posted some code that I copied directly from reflector after disassembling one Microsoft's .NET dlls. Shortly after a comment was posted (which has since been deleted) that it was illegal to do this and at the very least would affect the Mono team.

I understand the issues with Mono and in a case of better safe than sorry removed the code sample. But is it actually **illegal** to post disassembled code from a closed source project?

(In case it makes any difference the code was disassembled from System.Core and is not available in the released Microsoft source code)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378498/can-i-reflector-the-net-base-class-libraries-bcl

Comment: Re "***A*** reflector" and *"reflector"*? Don't you mean the *specific* product *"[.NET Reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector)"*? [Mark Seemann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377864/what-is-the-performance-of-the-last-extension-method-for-listt/1377905#1377905) references .NET Reflector.

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 7 years ago"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would normally depend on the EULA, and how enforcible it was in your jurisdiction. A typical clause in closed-source software is that you're not allowed to disassemble the code (and therefore publishing it elsewhere is incriminating yourself).

Comment: Looks like you are right - I read the EULA for the framework and it is an extension of the EULA for the OS that you run it on. As pointed out here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679695/is-it-possible-to-post-code-taken-from-the-net-framework-and-modified-online/679732#679732) disassembly is specifically disallowed in the Vista EULA. I assume it is the same for all versions of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Note that theoretically, since you must license your posts as CC-BY-SA, you should have the permission to license whatever you are posting as CC-BY-SA (it's public domain, or you are the copyright holder, or with permission from the copyright holder). It's extremely unlikely that you have such permission for posting what you need to use Reflector to see--unless what you are posting falls under [fair use](https://web.archive.org/web/20210605143659/https://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl102.html).